# Querying a MySQL database to get values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, metadata

I have two MySQL database tables:

motorhome

```
-----------------------
| id  | status | name |
-----------------------
|  1  | active | mh 1 |
|  2  | active | mh 2 |
-----------------------
```

motorhome_meta

```
----------------------------------------------
| id  | motorhome_id | meta_key | meta_value |
----------------------------------------------
|  1  | 1            | size     | large      |
|  2  | 1            | fuel     | petrol     |
|  3  | 2            | size     | small      |
|  4  | 2            | fuel     | petrol     |
----------------------------------------------
```

What I need is a query that will allow me to select a row from the `motorhome` table, with the values from the `motorhome_meta` table. Or in other words if I was selecting the row in the 
`motorhome` table with id 1.

```
----------------------------------------
| id  | status | name | size  | fuel   |
----------------------------------------
|  1  | active | mh 1 | large | petrol |
----------------------------------------
```

There are occasions where I might need to use a where statement against either table eg `WHERE motorhome.status='active'` or `WHERE motorhome_meta.meta_key='size'`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM motorhome AS m JOIN motorhome_meta AS mm ON m.id=motorhome_id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` to create columns from your rows of data:

```
select m.id,
  m.status,
  m.name,
  max(case when h.meta_key= 'size' then h.meta_value end) size,
  max(case when h.meta_key= 'fuel' then h.meta_value end) fuel
from motorhome m
inner join motorhome_meta h
  on m.id = h.motorhome_id
-- where m.id = 1
group by   m.id, m.status, m.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31dc84/1). This gives the result:

```
| ID | STATUS | NAME |  SIZE |   FUEL |
---------------------------------------
|  1 | active | mh 1 | large | petrol |
|  2 | active | mh 2 | small | petrol |
```

---

You can also use this variation, if there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(motorhome_id, meta_key)` combination:

```
select m.id,
  m.status,
  m.name,
  h1.meta_value  size,
  h2.meta_value  fuel
from motorhome m
left join motorhome_meta h1           -- or:  inner join
  on  m.id = h1.motorhome_id          -- depending on your need (or not)
  and h1.meta_key = 'size'            -- to show motorhomes
left join motorhome_meta h2           -- that have  only 'fuel'
  on  m.id = h2.motorhome_id          -- or only 'size'
  and h2.meta_key = 'fuel' ;
```

See: [SQL-Fiddle-2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31dc84/3)

Comment: Assuming m.id is UNIQUE, MySQL will forgive the omission of the remaining non-aggregated columns - but I suppose it's good practice.

Comment: @Strawberry That is correct but it is not allowed on other databases.  I prefer to write queries assuming that [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is turned on in MySQL, which is standard on other databases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more of a `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.status,
        a.name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key= 'size' THEN b.meta_value END) size,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key= 'fuel' THEN b.meta_value END) fuel
FROM    motorhome a
        INNER JOIN motorhome_meta b
            ON a.ID = b.motorhome_ID
WHERE   a.status = 'active' AND
        (
            (b.meta_key = 'size' AND b.meta_value = 'large') OR
            (b.meta_key = 'fuel' AND b.meta_value = 'petrol') 
        )
GROUP   BY a.id, a.status, a.name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e71/1)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════════╦══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ STATUS ║ NAME ║ SIZE  ║  FUEL  ║
╠════╬════════╬══════╬═══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ active ║ mh 1 ║ large ║ petrol ║
╚════╩════════╩══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```